# Can't upload dataset to BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, upload, postgresql-bigsql

I'm trying to upload the dataset from this link (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/aaditshukla/flipkart-fasion-products-dataset) on either format to BigQuery.

If I try to upload a xlsx file I get the following error:
Error while reading data, error message: The Apache Avro library failed to parse the header with the following error: Invalid data file. Magic does not match: bigstore/bigquery-prod-upload-us/prod-scotty-742294406158-0a961394-8a51-4e20-b60a-73171b3ede27 File: bigstore/bigquery-prod-upload-us/prod-scotty-742294406158-0a961394-8a51-4e20-b60a-73171b3ede27

If I try to upload a jason file, I get the following error:
Error while reading data, error message: Failed to parse JSON: No object found when new array is started.; BeginArray returned false File: prod-scotty-742294406158-0e3c245a-4029-47a0-bb46-796ac00b04b3

I have tried creating my own schema, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery doesn't support [xlsx files](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#load_nested_and_repeated_data).

The easiest way would be to convert the XLSX file to CSV, and then [load that one in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table). You can select "Schema Autodetect" option, or specify the schema yourself.

The JSON file was failing because BigQuery needs instead a [newline delimited JSON](https://jsonlines.org/). You will need to convert it.